# Ionic not destroying pages after leaving it

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I started working with Ionic (TypeScript + Angular) due to some needs on my job, I never coded for mobile before, this is my first time ever.

I got stuck with a issue that I got no idea how to fix it, let me try to explain the flows:

## Flow 1

1. **UserA** sign in with their user/password
2. **UserA** is redirected to the profile page after the login
3. **UserA** do logout

## Flow 2

1. **UserB** sign in with their user/password
2. **UserB** is redirected to the profile page after the login (and he see the ***UserA*** profile info)

## Considerations

I'm storing the session with @ionic/storage **BUT has nothing to do with storage issues**, I know that because after the logout I tried to *await session.get('user')* and it returns undefined, and after the new login I *await session.get('user')* and it shows the right user (the one that just connected)

## What I think it is?

I think that ionic is holding the page on the cache, when a new user sign the methods **constructor** and **ngOnInit** is not called again... the variables stays with the old user data and the view is rendered with wrong information.

I'm kinda sure this is the problem because is not every time that this bug happens, sometimes everything is rendered as it should be in the first place, but I don't know what to do :/

## Questions

Someone already had this issue? What did you do to fix this issue?

There is a way for me to tell ionic not to keep the page in cache?

There is a way to force the last content be destroyed after router.navigate() to another page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Ionic does not destroy pages - it keeps them in the DOM to enable travel via the back/forward buttons. In vanilla Angular routing, you can control this via RouteReuseStrategy but if you’re using ion-router-outlet, you cannot. ion-router-outlet implements a stack that stores navigation history, and will only run Ionic lifecycle hooks after a component has been created. You can use navigateRoot() to clear this stack, or switch to Angular’s router-outlet and router instead.

This is a significant flaw in my opinion, and is not documented well enough. There are many cases where it is not desirable to store a rendered component in the DOM indefinitely, and potentially can have significant performance impacts.

Comment: yeah thanks. I've spent weeks trying to figure out just what the hell is going on.

Comment: literally nothing makes sense especially when working with observables, then the whole app becomes an unpredictable shit show with observables firing all over the place without being destroyed. ion-router-outlet seems to fail when it's nested as well, then you have to switch to router-outlet, then the lifecycle events don't fire anymore on child pages and components.

Comment: not saying Ionic is bad though. I like it. but some of this was painful, even after going through the docs.

Comment: @dormant You should simply move your destroy logic into the ionic life-cycle hooks...

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue using **Ionic 4 Angular 8**. I fixed it using the `{ replaceUrl: true }` when the user clicks to logout. For instance:

```
logout() {
    ...
    this.router.navigate(["login"], { replaceUrl: true });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ionic will sometimes hold on too pages in the DOM for page transition/state reasons. Therefore, there are lifecycle methods that you can use to reset the state of your page when it is "reentered". The IonViewWillEnter lifecycle method will fire each time the user navigates to the page, regardless if its already in the DOM or not.  See here on the usage of the events: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Comment: this doesn't help if I want to unsubscribe observables

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>` with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. All lifecycle hooks of angular will start working and you can easily achieve your requirement but it may or may not be appropriate for the iconic project.

Instead of this, you can add a router event of Navigation check in the constructor and can do further implementation up to some extent.

For e.g.

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event : NavigationEnd) => {
  ...
})
```

**Second method :**

**Ionic has "Pages" instead of modules.** So you have to use `ionic generate page pageName` to create the pages/modules.
All the ionic lifecycle hooks will work in it like `ionViewWillEnter`, `ionViewDidLeave`, etc. So for main page you can create `layout` page(dashboard, other modules) and `auth` for login/logout/forgotpassword/etc.

Cut/Paste all your code from`ngOnit` to `ionViewWillEnter` and it will work properly.

Note: Ionic Components lifecyclehooks may not work properly. So take maximum use case of Pages.

Comment: I'm using `ion-tabs` so I can't replace it